# Resource recommendation for rotational physics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, resource-recommendations

What books an undergraduate needs to study to get a clear conception of rotational physics? I want books which are solely dedicated to rotational physics.

Comment: @David Z My question is about books solely related to rotational mechanics whereas your given link contains books giving only a fair share to rotational physics

Comment: Yes, rotational mechanics is contained within Newtonian mechanics, so to learn about rotational mechanics you should look at the books in the answers to the linked question.

Comment: I have seen them a long time ago. Even some books of that list are even in my possession

Comment: This post is not a duplicate! The other question asks for recommendations on elementary rotational dynamics based on Newtonian mechanics. No book on Newtonian mechanics (atleast not the books mentioned in the answers to that question) address gyroscopes and their applications, 3-d rotations, Euler angles, etc. I have been facing the same problem on my post. Moderators seem to be flagging posts as duplicate without careful attention.

Comment: This question is the subject of a [discussion on Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9648/44126).

Comment: Books of ruins(dynamics),dk Jha(rotational motion), sl loney(dynamics) may address your issue.. Also try some advanced engineering book Meriam & Kraige , Beer & Johnston.