# Resource recommendation for a thorough coverage of rotational mechanics (especially gyroscopes)

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, resource-recommendations, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

I am looking for a book which covers classical rotational mechanics in full detail using all the specialized powerful tools of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism (if needed).

I have already studied [Classical mechanics by Goldstein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8131758915) and [Analytical Mechanics by Hand and Finch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521575729) as a reference alongside a one-semester undergraduate course on classical mechanics. And although I found rotational mechanics most interesting I could not grasp it as well as I would like to through these books. I suppose it is because neither of them offers a thorough discussion of this topic.

**Note:** This is not a regular "recommend me some books for classical mechanics" query. I could I have easily Googled that up if that was the case. What I seek is a particular emphasis on or an exclusive coverage of rotational mechanics with the help of the most advanced tools that we currently have. That is particularly hard to find because most classical mechanics books and courses aim only to prepare students for quantum mechanics or chaos theory and so give rotational mechanics only a brief treatment.

My aim specifically is to thoroughly understand gyroscopes and to develop an intuition about them for application in toys, experimental demonstrations, etc. Any resource on theory, mathematical development, application or history would be appreciated.

Comment: @Qmechanic, this post is not a duplicate! The other question asks for recommendations on elementary rotational dynamics based on Newtonian mechanics. No book on Newtonian mechanics (atleast not the books mentioned in the answers to that question) address gyroscopes and their applications, 3-d rotations, Euler angles, etc.

Comment: In fact, the question explicitly mentions help on "Kinematics, Newton laws, 2D Motion of Object, etc.". Not what I am asking for.

Comment: Note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE, cf. various meta posts. It seems to be a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309624/2451

Comment: Re res. recom. I was under the impression that if "What the book covers
How it covers it — is it rigorous? Intuitive? How is the writer's style?
What are the prerequisites?" has been specified, the question must be allowed. They are not restricted only discouraged if the question is not precise enough. That is how Math SE treated one of my questions anyhow.

Comment: The other alleged duplicate is neither a precise and detailed question nor has it received any attention. (I guess it might if someone removes the duplicate tag from it. Because it is not a question on Newtonian mechanics.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9648/2451